# .Net MVC 4 View Engine WebForm

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms, razor, viewengine

This is a quite interesting question, in my opinion.
I have a strongly typed view using the WebForm view Engine, I don't know if changing to razor would solve my problem.

**PROBLEM:**
I have one view with a list of cars, so of type `IList <Car>`.
And I have a button **"Create a new Car"** that popups, the popup is a form that is hidded and you call a jQuery UI command `$('formName').dialog()` to popup it, this form has the attributes of the possible new car, so probably a new view with a strongly typed `Car`. After fill in the form the database should be populated with the new car, and the list of cars should be refreshed using Ajax.
The main problem is that I can't use HTML Helpers to `IList <Car>` and for `Car` at the same time.

**Briefly:** *What is the strongly type for that view ? Is it possible to define two views and the other one call using pop-up? Changing it to Razor would solve my problem?*

Best regards,

Tito Morais

Comment: I can't tell what your problem is. But there's nothing in Razor you can't do in WebForms. I prefer Razor myself, but changing won't solve your 'problem'.

Comment: Nobody will provide a solid answer unless you post your code sample here. I sort of understood what you need but that could be wrong so post the code, pls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mix the views for listing the cars and creating a new car together.

For instance, you can make a popup that dynamically loads a "_CreateCar" partial view, using jQuery dialog or similar component. Then when the partial view is completed, reload the list view using another Ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not so much an elegant solution is to create a complex view model like:

```
class ListAndCreate
{
 public IList<Car> AllCars {get;set;}
 public Car NewCar {get;set;}
}
```

IMO this is *correct* since that one view is responsible for listing all cars and creating a new one. Now, I'm assuming that your `NewCar` has values coming from your controller or something, where you need to pass a model to your view.

The other approach, that @Jonas mentions is also correct and more unitized. You could create a partial view `_CreateCar` with type `Car`, render it with Jquery/Ajax to load it into a dialog/popup and have the form POST to a `Create(Car c)` method in your controller.